# Define multiple classes in one variable and then retrieve them

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

How can i define multiple classes in one variable and then retrieve them easily? I was thinking something like

```
var classes = getElementsByClassName('class1, class2, class3');
var class1 = classes[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

You ***can*** do it with `getElementsByClassName`, if you separate each class with spaces (not commas):

```js
console.log([...document.getElementsByClassName("red blue")]);
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="red blue">1</p>
<p class="red yellow">2</p>
<p class="red blue">3</p>
```

You could also use a simple `querySelectorAll` call:

```
var classes = document.querySelectorAll('.class1, .class2, .class3');
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible using `document.getElementsByClassName()`

Instead, you have to use `document.querySelectorAll()`

```
var classes = document.querySelectorAll('.class1, .class2, .class3');
```